# Convolution of cosine and shifted unit step

Tags: convolution

I'm trying to understand the basics of a convolution and have troubles with the following task:

$$ x_1 = \cos(2 \pi t ) \cdot u(t) $$
$$ x_2 = u(t-0,5)$$

The task is to compute the convolution $$x_1 \ast x_2 $$

So I tried to compute the integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = x_{1}(\tau)\cdot  x_{2}(t-\tau) \, d\tau $$

Since the cosine starts at $0$ and the unit step is mirrored in the convolution, I start the integral from $0$ instead of $-\infty$.

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} = \cos(2\pi\tau)\cdot  u(t-\tau-0.5) \, d\tau $$

Now this is where I'm a bit confused. What about the upper bound of the integral?

Does someone know how I can continue from here?

Comment: $t - \tau - 1/2 < 0 \implies \tau > t - 1/2  \implies u(t - \tau - 1/2) = 0$ so $\int_0^{t - 1/2}$

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks, but what does  $t - \tau - 1/2 < 0 $ mean, or how did you get this.

Comment: $u(t-\tau-1/2) = 0 \implies t - \tau - 1/2 < 0$

Comment: you should also learn by heart that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are causal, then $x_1 \ast x_2(t) = \int_0^t x_1(\tau) x_2(t-\tau) d\tau$ (which is also causal...)

Comment: Ok I think I, got it. Thanks!